# Lauching rundeck job with arguments with curl

Tags: curl, rundeck

I want to launch rundeck job with gitlab-ci after a commit. So i use curl command to call rundeck job. But there is a problem the option values are not used in my job, the default values are used. But my xml response show that the argString is present.

The command i used :

```
curl -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: <my_token>' --data-urlencode 'argString=-LOCAL_REPO /home/rundeck/ -FILE_NAME archive_test.zip' 'https://<url:port>/api/1/job/<job_id>/run' -k
```

XML response :

```
...
        <name>TEST_2args</name>
        <group></group>
        <project>Rundeck</project>
        <description>Job test </description>
        <options>
          <option name='LOCAL_REPO' value='/tmp/' />
          <option name='FILE_NAME' value='archive.zip' />
        </options>
      </job>
      <description>whoami ('Who am i ?') [... 3 steps]</description>
      <argstring>-LOCAL_REPO /home/rundeck/ -FILE_NAME archive_test.zip</argstring>
    </execution>
  </executions>
```

I don't want to use the default values but the option i passed in arguments.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record answer: You can launch it in the following way (i included the node filter if anybody needs it):

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# protocol
protocol="http"
format="json"

# basic rundeck info
rdeck_host="yournode"
rdeck_port="4440"
rdeck_api="36"
rdeck_token="0jEkMXbPBUzx984HeM3RUDQSXg4yJzyT"

# specific api call info
rdeck_job="0745efe5-17c2-44cd-bb59-26706331ea2f"
rdeck_filter="node01"
option_value="YOUR_VALUE"

# api call
curl --location --request POST "$protocol://$rdeck_host:$rdeck_port/api/$rdeck_api/job/$rdeck_job/run" \
  --header "Accept: application/$format" \
  --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: $rdeck_token" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/$format" \
  --data "{ \"argString\":\"-opt1 $option_value \", \"filter\":\"$rdeck_filter\" }"
```

It works with the following job definition example:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: f2dc19f0-b099-46c6-a50d-a6848797851d
  loglevel: INFO
  name: HelloWorld
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: false
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: ''
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  options:
  - name: opt1
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: echo "hola ${option.opt1}"
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: f2dc19f0-b099-46c6-a50d-a6848797851d
```